# Не получается обратиться к vp от binding (Привязка adapter к ViewPager)

Tags: android, binding, android-viewpager

Пытаюсь сделать приложение по уроку - https://neco-desarrollo.es/2022/06/weather-app-7-viewpager-tablayout, возникла проблема с привязкой adapter к ViewPager, рассматриваемый код в ссылке выше, мой - ниже. Собственно, ни с = with(binding), ни с непосредственно binding.vp не получается обратиться к vp для привязки адаптера, почему так?

```
package com.example.weather.Fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
import com.example.weather.Adapters.ViePageAdapter
import com.example.weather.R
import com.example.weather.databinding.FragmentMainBinding
import java.security.Permission
import java.util.jar.Manifest
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator

class MainFragment : Fragment() {


    private lateinit var arLauncher : ActivityResultLauncher<String>
    private val fragmentsList = listOf<Fragment>( //список фрагментов для переключения в пейджере
        HourFragment.newInstance(),
        DaysFragment.newInstance()
    )
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentMainBinding

    override fun onCreateView( //до создания View
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root //возврат View
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { //когда View уже точно создана
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    }

    private fun init() = with(binding) {
        val adapter = ViePageAdapter(activity as FragmentActivity, fragmentsList)
        //Вот здесь должно прописываться vp.adapter...
        //binding.vp тоже не работает
    }

    private fun permissionListener()
    {
        arLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission())
        {
            //объект логического типа в зависимости от того, дал ли пользователь свое разрешение
        }
    }

    private fun checkPermission()
    {
        if (!(isPermissionTrue(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))) //если
        // разрешение ещё не дано
        {
            permissionListener() //вызов функции, спрашивающей разрешение на что-то,
            // ответ - дол ли пользователь разрешение?
            arLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        }
    }

    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
    }
}
```

Comment: К слову, представлен только код MainFragment, т.к остальное в принципе не имеет значения, проблема с местным binding.

Comment: судя по всему проблема таки в `FragmentMainBinding`, что есть `vp`? `ViewPager`? тогда попробуйте  `(vp as? ViewPager)?.adapter = adapter`